# 'IME is Disabled' when set focus to TextBox

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I've 2 textbox and a button. The 1st textbox is for entry, the 2nd textbox displayed the time when the button is clicked.

When Chinese characters are entered in the 1st textbox and the button is clicked, tbMsg.Focus() causes 'IME is Disabled'. Chinese character therefore cannot be entered anymore.

How to avoid 'IME is Disabled' from happening?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbMsg" runat="server" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"
                 Width="329px"  />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="150"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Time" onclick="Button1_Click" />
  </div>
</form>
```

With the following code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    tbMsg.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/564476-how-enable-ime-custom-usercontrol) is a link where you can find somebody having a similar issue and finally solving it.

Hope that'll help you.

(I tried to just make a comment but can't...)

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

The solution is for windows textbox user control, and don't seem to be applicable in the asp.net page, unless I missed something.

I was hoping applying style="ime-mode:active" on the textbox will resolve this, but not successful.

     <asp:TextBox ID="tbMsg" runat="server" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"
                 Width="329px" style="ime-mode:active" />